# Compact Framework - Retrieve a list of countries and regions

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, cultureinfo

Afternoon people!

I'm trying to implement a list of counties on my Compact Framework (Mobile) application.

I can do this easily in the full .Net framework with CultureInfo.GetCultures(..etc). However, the CF seems to be missing this feature?

Is there any way I can return a list of countries (and regions if possible) that I can populate into a ComboBox?

The OS has a list of countries, so there must be a way to do it?

I look forward to hearing back!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace OpenNETCF.Globalization
{
    public class CultureInfoHelper
    {
        private delegate int EnumLocalesHandler(string lpLocaleString);

        private static EnumLocalesHandler m_localesDelegate;

        private static List<CultureInfo> m_cultures;

        private static int EnumLocalesProc(string locale)
        {
            try
            {
                m_cultures.Add(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(
                    int.Parse(locale, NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
            }
            catch
            {
                // failed for this locale - ignore and continue
            }

            return 1;
        }

        public static CultureInfo[] GetCultures()
        {
            if (m_localesDelegate == null)
            {
                m_cultures = new List<CultureInfo>();
                m_localesDelegate = new EnumLocalesHandler(EnumLocalesProc);
                IntPtr fnPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(
                    m_localesDelegate);
                int success = EnumSystemLocales(fnPtr, LCID_INSTALLED);
            }

            return m_cultures.ToArray();
        }

        private const int LCID_INSTALLED = 0x01;
        private const int LCID_SUPPORTED = 0x02;

        [DllImport("coredll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int EnumSystemLocales(
            IntPtr lpLocaleEnumProc, uint dwFlags);
    }
}
```

Usage looks like this:

```
using OpenNETCF.Globalization;
....
static void Main()
{
    foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfoHelper.GetCultures())
    {            
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("0x{0:x2}({1}) : {2}", ci.LCID, ci.Name, ci.EnglishName));
    }
}
```

And output looks like this:

```
0x402(bg-BG) : Bulgarian (Bulgaria)
0x403(ca-ES) : Catalan (Catalan)
0x405(cs-CZ) : Czech (Czech Republic)
0x406(da-DK) : Danish (Denmark)
0x407(de-DE) : German (Germany)
0x408(el-GR) : Greek (Greece)
0x409(en-US) : English (United States)
...
0x400a(es-BO) : Spanish (Bolivia)
0x440a(es-SV) : Spanish (El Salvador)
0x480a(es-HN) : Spanish (Honduras)
0x4c0a(es-NI) : Spanish (Nicaragua)
0x500a(es-PR) : Spanish (Puerto Rico)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly CultureInfo.GetCultures method is not supported by .NET Compact Framework but you can iterate through available cultures on the device by checking on CultureType Enumeration. Here's[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.culturetypes.aspx) a link to MSDN with some explanation and examples